# Css Transition a picture to the left overlapping text

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make an image expand left, overflowing the div block it's in to overlap some text. It's working fine without transition, but i am utterly incapable of producing the effect using transitions, i've been at it for hours, googling about, but It hasn't helped much.

Initially i thought i could work with the top and left properties to change the image while expanding it, but it didn't work.

Heres the code without transition.

I'm simply out of ideas, so if someone would show me how, and tell me why, it would just be awesome.

```
 <head>
    <style type="text/CSS">
        Img:hover{
            overflow:visible;
            position:relative;
            left:-360px;
            top:0px;
            width:400px;
            height:640px;
        }

        .iconImg {
            width:40px;
            height:64px;   
        }

        .divBox{
            float:left;
            width:40px;
            height:64px;    
        }

        .divText{
            display:block;
            width: 400px;
            height:640px;
            float:left;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<h1>Nyheder</h1>
<div class="">
    <span class="">
        test af Skabelon
    </span>
</div>
<div class="divtext">
    <span>Dette er en test som skal bruge mere text for at test om billedet kan flyde henover det, mere, mere, mere, mere tekst</span>
</div>

<div class="divBox">
    <img class="transitionClass iconImg" src="hej.png">
</div>
```

The Image used is one with a simple resolution of: 400x640.

Comment: can you do a fiddle of what you already worked on? what you need is not very clear

Comment: Does this help? `transition: all 0.2s linear;`. Put it in Img:hover.

Comment: So your document really doesn't have `<body>` ??

Answer (score 0):

I put this together. Hopefully it answers your question

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qIzHg

the main part of the transition-ing is:

```
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
```

Then I used `z-index` for the overlapping

EDIT:
Try this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qIzHg

I put in `float:right;` and changed a few other things around.

Comment: It ALMOST does - Only, i can do the samething, my code wasn't as pretty, but it worked. The thing is to get the picture to be on the right, and then transition left, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Give me a few mins and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: You may want to be careful with transitioning *all* properties, as in the future you might get some unwanted behavior. It's better practice to transition only the properties you want to animate.

Comment: I must say:
1. I still don't understand why exactly it animates left.
2. Say i put this in an area on a webpage with a limited amount of space, the general idea is that the picture will "overlay" the text while it's being hovered